# sample ts files for mpeg-ts player

Tags: android, media-player, gstreamer, transport-stream

I configured gstreamer on eclipse and built a media player accepting transport stream files. Now for testing, I want to download some ts files but I am not getting any. I already tried the link, http://www.w6rz.net/ but the frame rate is very high so the audio and video is not getting synchronized. Any ideas?

Comment: And the-2 is for?? I should be informed what this question is lacking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for TS Files: you can check the following links:

https://github.com/tsduck/tsduck

https://tsduck.io/streams/

If you are looking for why AV not getting played: You may need to re-check your pipeline and use the capabilities to set framerate for the audio/video sink

Comment: Thank you. As I am using gstreamer in eclipse, I have no idea where to use either gst-launch or pipeline. In adb shell? Can you guide or provide me details on it please?

Comment: Sorry.. I dont have any idea of GStreamer on eclipse..

Comment: These links are dead.

Comment: Is there any h265 (hevc) TS file (which has multiple 'picture parameter set') available?